# yq - inserting JSON as a raw string

Tags: json, github-actions, yq

I am writing a GitHub Action that does some CD and it uses `yq` to insert environment variables into a yaml file for deployment.

I'm trying to read a JSON from a GH secret that will eventually be read from env and loaded into python, where said string will be evaluated as a dictionary.

Running this in a terminal, for example:

```sh
yq -i '.value="{\"web\": \"test\"}"' test.yaml
```

Gives me:

```yaml
value: '{"web": "test"}'
```

But in a Github Action, where I am doing this:

```yaml
env:
  JSON="{\"web\": \"test\"}"
...
  - name: test
    run : |
        yq -i '
          .value=strenv(JSON)
        ' deployment.yaml
```

Gives me:

```sh
Error: Bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

Doing other variations of that string, e.g. `'{\"web\": \"test\"}'`, `'\"{\"web\": \"test\"}\"'` etc also gives me the same error.

I've tried searching on the `yq` repository and consulted the documentation but can't seem to find what I am looking for.

To summarise, my problem is that I want to read a JSON string *as a string* when it is evaluated by yq.

Comment: some typos and one more thing I need to point out:
the line with the env-var should read JSON: ${{ secrets.JSON }} -- but the string value in there is what was evaluated when I was running the action.

Comment: Defining the variable as `JSON='{"web": "test"}'` and running `yq` as `.value=strenv(JSON)` ?

Comment: Depending on how I did the quotes it seems to either create a bad expression with unmatched texts or yq evaluates it into a yml.

Comment: That looks like the right yq command to me - which version of yq are you using? Can you echo out the variable?  Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of yq users has recently contributed to yq's github action docs regarding using env variables in github actions - it may help here:

```yaml
  - name: Get an entry with a variable that might contain dots or spaces
    id: get_username
    uses: mikefarah/yq@master
    with:
      cmd: yq '.all.children.["${{ matrix.ip_address }}"].username' ops/inventories/production.yml
  - name: Reuse a variable obtained in another step
    run: echo ${{ steps.get_username.outputs.result }}
```

See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/github-action for more info.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq